# Discover what process/query is using the oracle SGA

Tags: performance, oracle, debugging, statistics, oracleinternals

I have a query to monitor SGA (non-)utilisation:

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 " SGA Free " from v$sgastat where name='free memory';
```

That's great, but I need more detail about what exactly is using the space. Essentially, I'm looking for clues to tell me more precisely what might be wrong with this (rather large application).

`select * from v$sgastat` does not give me anything that I recognise as a developer - at least not without some pointers.

Comment: You're monitoring SGA usage to see what is wrong with an application?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that I use to see pool size in the SGA

```
SELECT POOL, NAME, Round(BYTES/1024/1024,2) Mb
FROM V$SGASTAT WHERE POOL LIKE '%pool%'
order by 1,3
```

Looks great in SQL Developer as a BAR_HORIZ_STACK chart.

All the information you need ought to be in the V$SGASTAT view. Remember that it's shared space, so it's difficult to tie usage to particular processes.

Comment: This answer covers topics specifically excluded from the scope of the question.

Comment: Actually, remembering its shared space proved to be a little useful, thanks.